# Sending gratuitous ARP messages

Tags: c, linux, networking

I am looking for a way to programmatically (in C) send gratuitous ARP messages in a Linux user-space application. I noticed there are are some files for configuring ARP in procfs at

```
/proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/<interface_name>
```

Is there a way to do this with an ioctl call to the corresponding network interface?

Comment: http://usuaris.tinet.cat/sag/send_arp.htm, http://www.emoticode.net/c/how-to-send-an-arp-packet-with-libnet.html

Answer (score 4):

Using [scapy](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/):

```
from scapy.all import *

SELF_MAC = '02:02:02:02:02:02'    # fill in with your MAC address
BCAST_MAC = 'ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff'

def create_ARP_request_gratuituous(ipaddr_to_broadcast):
    arp = ARP(psrc=ipaddr_to_broadcast,
              hwsrc=SELF_MAC,
              pdst=ipaddr_to_broadcast)
    return Ether(dst=BCAST_MAC) / arp

# and then call sendp() with the result
```

Comment: The python solution is nice, but I am looking for a "C" solution.

Comment: Why the quotes? C is a language.